# Use chance plugin in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Is it possible to use chance plugin with cypress.io?

https://chancejs.com

I installed plugin via npm to node_modules\chance and edited /plugins/index.js file, but still get error from cypress - Can't start, The plugins file is missing or invalid.

If using this plugin is impossible - what do you recommend to write tests basing on registration new users? I planned to use chance to generate "random: emails and passwords.

```
// ***********************************************************
// This example plugins/index.js can be used to load plugins
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off loading
// the plugins file with the 'pluginsFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/plugins-guide
// ***********************************************************

// This function is called when a project is opened or re-opened (e.g. due to
// the project's config changing)

module.exports = on => {
  on("task", {
    chance: require("chance"),
  });
};
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
}
```

Comment: That doesn't currently make sense, `on` expects the second argument to be a *callback*. Read https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide.html

Comment: So any recommendations how I should plan tests regarding new accounts create? Only way is to use own copy of backend?

Comment: That's a totally separate question, I'm just saying you can't use chance *like that* because that's not how you use plugins in Cypress (also I don't think it's a Cypress plugin). But I definitely wouldn't recommend generating random users in the real database as a testing strategy, either.

Answer (score 4):

Just install chancejs with npm:

```
npm install chance
```

Then just use it in your test for example:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import Chance from 'Chance';

const chance = new Chance();

describe('Testing chance', function (){
   const company =chance.company();
   it('type company in duckduckgo.com', function () {
        cy.visit('https://duckduckgo.com/')
        cy.get('#search_form_input_homepage')
        .should('be.visible')
        .type(company)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`cypress/support/index.js`:

Override the default `task` command so that you can supply multiple arguments as you'd normally.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('task', (origFn, name, ...args) => {
    return origFn(name, args);
});

// if you're gonna use `chance` plugin a lot, you can also add a custom command
Cypress.Commands.add('chance', (...args) => {
    return cy.task('chance', ...args);
});
```

`cypress/plugins/index.js`:

Wrap the tasks in function that will spread the arguments, and also handle a case when the task doesn't return anything and return `null` instead, so that cypress doesn't complain.

```js
const chance = require('chance').Chance();
// lodash should be installed alongside with cypress.
// If it doesn't resolve, you'll need to install it manually
const _ = require('lodash');

on('task', _.mapValues(
    {
        chance ( method, ...args ) {
            return chance[method](...args);
        }
    },
    func => args => Promise.resolve( func(...args) )
        // ensure we return null instead of undefined to satisfy cy.task
        .then( val => val === undefined ? null : val )
));
```

In your spec file:

```js
describe('test', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        cy.document().then( doc => {
            doc.body.innerHTML = `<input class="email">`;
        });

        cy.task('chance', 'email', {domain: 'example.com'}).then( email => {
            cy.get('.email').type(email);
        });

        // or use the custom `chance` command we added
        cy.chance('email', {domain: 'test.com'}).then( email => {
            cy.get('.email').type(email);
        });
    });
});
```